# iOS http random timeout for specific internet provider

Tags: ios, ssl, networking, tcp, handshake

I am facing a very strange issue which happens in particular conditions.

**My iOS app experiences random http response timeouts only for builds in a certain environment (pre-prod) and only for users connected to the wifi network for a specific internet provider.**

Timeouts happens to different API calls without any particular pattern. Every call work correctly with a 0.2-0.3 seconds response time and then suddenly there is a timeout.

Here's the log when the timeout occurs;

```html
2021-09-02 22:02:02.681343+0200 MyApp[6252:516103] REQUEST GET /api/v4/code/88020000/zone
2021-09-02 22:02:02.682045+0200 MyApp[6252:516103] REQUEST QUERY: prog=1
2021-09-02 22:02:02.682430+0200 MyApp[6252:516103] REQUEST BODY:
2021-09-02 22:02:10.828523+0200 MyApp[6252:516712] Connection 32: received failure notification
2021-09-02 22:02:10.835469+0200 MyApp[6252:516712] Connection 32: failed to connect 1:60, reason -1
2021-09-02 22:02:10.835533+0200 MyApp[6252:516712] Connection 32: encountered error(1:60)
2021-09-02 22:02:10.842757+0200 MyApp[6252:516712] Task <A3B9C549-3688-40D7-9B87-E1C6F3034D44>.<1> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1001 [1:60])
2021-09-02 22:02:10.843106+0200 MyApp[6252:516601] Task <A3B9C549-3688-40D7-9B87-E1C6F3034D44>.<1> finished with error [-1001] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "Tempo di richiesta scaduto." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60, NSUnderlyingError=0x283fbe880 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <A3B9C549-3688-40D7-9B87-E1C6F3034D44>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <A3B9C549-3688-40D7-9B87-E1C6F3034D44>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Tempo di richiesta scaduto., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://46.137.72.16/api/v4/code/88020000/zone?prog=1, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://46.137.72.16/api/v4/code/88020000/zone?prog=1, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2021-09-02 22:02:10.843195+0200 Caleffi Code[6252:516601] HTTP RESPONSE CODE: 0
```

Here's a recap;

- The timeout does not happen with Android.
- The timeout does not happen in cellular network.
- The timeout does not happen with other WiFi networks.
- The timeout happens also if I change the DNS address.

These points have been verified on two different phones and networks.

Is anyone ever faced anything like that?
Any input would be very appreciated.

### Update

I ran a build with the flag enabling the CFNetwork verbose logging and found out there is a problem before the TLS handshaking.
Apparently there is a TCP packet which receives no response.
Here's the log of the packet sending attempts:

```html
default 19:31:33.594324+0200    Code Dev    tcp_output [C117.1.1:3] flags=[SEC] seq=1500167631, ack=0, win=65535 state=SYN_SENT rcv_nxt=0, snd_una=1500167631\
default 19:31:33.751463+0200    Code Dev    tcp_output [C117.1.1:3] flags=[S] seq=1500167631, ack=0, win=65535 state=SYN_SENT rcv_nxt=0, snd_una=1500167631\
default 19:31:33.909903+0200    Code Dev    tcp_output [C117.1.1:3] flags=[S] seq=1500167631, ack=0, win=65535 state=SYN_SENT rcv_nxt=0, snd_una=1500167631\
default 19:31:34.070595+0200    Code Dev    tcp_timers [C117.1.1:3] retransmit SYN seq=1500167631 3\
default 19:31:34.071046+0200    Code Dev    tcp_output [C117.1.1:3] flags=[S] seq=1500167631, ack=0, win=65535 state=SYN_SENT rcv_nxt=0, snd_una=1500167631\
default 19:31:34.231504+0200    Code Dev    tcp_timers [C117.1.1:3] retransmit SYN seq=1500167631 4\
default 19:31:34.232103+0200    Code Dev    tcp_output [C117.1.1:3] flags=[S] seq=1500167631, ack=0, win=65535 state=SYN_SENT rcv_nxt=0, snd_una=1500167631\
default 19:31:34.393184+0200    Code Dev    tcp_timers [C117.1.1:3] retransmit SYN seq=1500167631 5\
default 19:31:34.393703+0200    Code Dev    tcp_output [C117.1.1:3] flags=[S] seq=1500167631, ack=0, win=65535 state=SYN_SENT rcv_nxt=0, snd_una=1500167631\
default 19:31:34.601145+0200    Code Dev    tcp_timers [C117.1.1:3] retransmit SYN seq=1500167631 6\
default 19:31:34.601669+0200    Code Dev    tcp_output [C117.1.1:3] flags=[S] seq=1500167631, ack=0, win=65535 state=SYN_SENT rcv_nxt=0, snd_una=1500167631\
default 19:31:35.011084+0200    Code Dev    tcp_timers [C117.1.1:3] retransmit SYN seq=1500167631 7\
default 19:31:35.011873+0200    Code Dev    tcp_output [C117.1.1:3] flags=[S] seq=1500167631, ack=0, win=65535 state=SYN_SENT rcv_nxt=0, snd_una=1500167631\
default 19:31:35.824927+0200    Code Dev    tcp_timers [C117.1.1:3] retransmit SYN seq=1500167631 8\
default 19:31:35.825392+0200    Code Dev    tcp_output [C117.1.1:3] flags=[S] seq=1500167631, ack=0, win=65535 state=SYN_SENT rcv_nxt=0, snd_una=1500167631\
default 19:31:37.448041+0200    Code Dev    tcp_timers [C117.1.1:3] retransmit SYN seq=1500167631 9\
default 19:31:37.448404+0200    Code Dev    tcp_output [C117.1.1:3] flags=[S] seq=1500167631, ack=0, win=65535 state=SYN_SENT rcv_nxt=0, snd_una=1500167631\
default 19:31:40.685223+0200    Code Dev    tcp_timers [C117.1.1:3] retransmit SYN seq=1500167631 10\
default 19:31:40.685735+0200    Code Dev    tcp_output [C117.1.1:3] flags=[S] seq=1500167631, ack=0, win=65535 state=SYN_SENT rcv_nxt=0, snd_una=1500167631\
default 19:31:47.156089+0200    Code Dev    tcp_timers [C117.1.1:3] retransmit SYN seq=1500167631 11\
default 19:31:47.156443+0200    Code Dev    tcp_output [C117.1.1:3] flags=[S] seq=1500167631, ack=0, win=65535 state=SYN_SENT rcv_nxt=0, snd_una=1500167631\
default 19:31:53.621865+0200    Code Dev    tcp_timers [C117.1.1:3] retransmit SYN seq=1500167631 12\
default 19:31:53.622248+0200    Code Dev    tcp_output [C117.1.1:3] flags=[S] seq=1500167631, ack=0, win=65535 state=SYN_SENT rcv_nxt=0, snd_una=1500167631\
```

Server side I noticed the packets arrive correctly and the response is sent.
Here's the tcpdump with an example of reception and then response sending.

```html
17:31:33.671815 IP <IP_ADDRESS>.23007 > <IP_ADDRESS>.443: Flags [SEW], seq 1500167631, win 65535, options [mss 1440,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 2931883793 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 0040 0000 4000 2b06 c6e5 92f1 4880  E..@..@.+.....H.
    0x0010:  ac1e 0143 59df 01bb 596a bdcf 0000 0000  ...CY...Yj......
    0x0020:  b0c2 ffff 8cd7 0000 0204 05a0 0103 0305  ................
    0x0030:  0101 080a aec0 ff11 0000 0000 0402 0000  ................
17:31:33.671915 IP <IP_ADDRESS>.443 > <IP_ADDRESS>.23007: Flags [S.E], seq 3178758300, ack 1500167632, win 65160, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 886489627 ecr 2931883793,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    0x0000:  4500 003c 0000 4000 3f06 b2e9 ac1e 0143  E..<..@.?......C
    0x0010:  92f1 4880 01bb 59df bd78 009c 596a bdd0  ..H...Y..x..Yj..
    0x0020:  a052 fe88 8901 0000 0204 05b4 0402 080a  .R..............
    0x0030:  34d6 c21b aec0 ff11 0103 0307            4...........
```

Unfortunately the response packet seems to never reach the TCP stack in the iOS device.

Strange thing is that meanwhile other TCP connections keep working smoothly.